# Parse through all files from all the subfolders of a folder

Tags: vb.net, file

I want to parse through all the files from the subfolders of a folder. To be more precise, I want to check if any of the files in any folder is the same as a string already stored in a variable. I have the following code: 
 Const fpath2 As String = "C:\ProjectArtist\"

```
    Dim folders() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\ProjectArtist\")
    For Each folder As String In folders
            %% check file name if it's same with variable
    Next
```

How do I modify it in order to do the same for all the subfolders in fpath2?

Comment: Did you take a look at the [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles) documentation? There's an overload, `SearchOption`. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try it as soon as I am available and let you know.